# Is it possible to change color of axis labels and format them jsxgraph?

Tags: javascript

I created ticks using following code:

```
xticks=plot.create('ticks',[xaxis, 2]);
```

Is it possible to  change color of labels and format label values (like adding custom string)?

`xticks.label.setAttribute({strokeColor:"red"})` doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-object label does not work for tick labels, since usually there is more than one label. But one can change the visual appearance of the labels by providing the label sub-attribute.

```
xaxis = board.create('axis', [[0,0],[1,0]]);
xaxis.removeAllTicks();
xticks = board.create('ticks',[xaxis, 2], {
    drawLabels: true,
    strokeColor: 'red',
    label: {
        offset: [-4, -15],
        strokeColor: 'blue'
    }
});
```

Another possibility is to provide the same information as ticks sub-attribute:

```
xaxis = board.create('axis', [[0,0],[1,0]], {
            ticks: {
                drawLabels: true,
                strokeColor: 'red',
                label: {
                    offset: [-4, -15],
                    strokeColor: 'blue'
                }
            }
        });
```

Sorry for the late answer.